# Numpy Swap/Substitute NoneType Entry with Numpy Array (i.e. vector)

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.5, nonetype

Given a numpy array containing two types of elements:

1. "numpy.ndarray" entries and
2. "NoneType" entries

How do I replace all "NoneType" entries with e.g. np.zeros(some_shape)?
Could this be also done for any type of single elements like scalar for instance instead of NoneType?

Example:

```
test_array=
    array([[array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), ..., None, None,
    None],
   [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), ..., None, None,
    None],
   [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), ...,
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), None, None],
   ..., 
   [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), ...,
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), None],
   [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), ...,
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), None],
   [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), ...,
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object)
```

where an array within test_array might look like this:

```
test_array[323]=
   array([array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), None, None], dtype=object)
```

And I want to replace those "None" entries with a zero-vector of same length as the other vectors (here position 0 to 3).
So that my result for each array (test_array[i] within test_array would look like this:

```
test_array[131]=
   array([array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
   array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)], dtype=object)
```

So I would like to fill all None entries with np.zeros arrays. There does exists the numpy function np.nan_to_num but this does not help me because I would need something like "np.nan_to_array".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would not use a `for` loop with NumPy, but in your case you have an object array which is anyway not very efficient, and dealing with the combination of `None` and sub-arrays stored as objects is very tricky.  So, keep it simple:

```
prototype = a[0]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x is None:
        a[i] = np.zeros_like(prototype)
```

Of course you'll need to find a `prototype` if `a[0]` is None.  That's left as an exercise.

Comment: This is not working for me, can it be, that there is another for loop missing after we have fetched a subarray of the main array? Because the if-statement "if x is None" is always false because each x is a vaild numpy array. What do you think?

Comment: @SolingerMUC: Oh, I wrote this against your inner array.  Yes, you'll need to put one more `for` loop around it.  Give it a try.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help :)